# How to access variable dynamically inside an anonymous function/closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, dynamic-variables

To keep the global namespace clean, my JavaScript code is wrapped like this:

```
(function() {
    /* my code */
})();
```

Now I have some variables declared in this scope which I want to access using a variable variable name (e.g. the name is `'something' + someVar`).
In the global scope I'd simply use `window['varname']`, but obviously that doesn't work.

Is there a good way to do what I want? If not I could simply put those variables inside an object to use the array notation...

Note: `eval('varname')` is not an acceptable solution. So please don't suggest that.

Comment: Could you say more specifically what it is you want to do when you want to "access them dynamically"? Do you want to access them outside the function? That's not possible AFAIK.

Comment: No, i just want to access them without hardcoding the variable name - but from inside my function.

Comment: "Dynamically" - what scope do you mean?

Comment: With "dynamically" i mean with a dynamically generated variable name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good question because `this` doesn't point to the anonymous function, otherwise you would obviously just use `this['something'+someVar]`.  Even using the deprecated `arguments.callee` doesn't work here because the internal variables aren't properties of the function.  I think you will have to do exactly what you described by creating either a holder object...

```
(function() {
  var holder = { something1: 'one', something2: 2, something3: 'three' };

  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    console.log(holder['something'+i]);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(globals) {
    /* do something */
    globals[varname] = yourvar;
})(yourglobals);
```

Comment: "To keep the global namespace clean" - so obviously I do not want to add it to the global namespace.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: `globals` doesn't necessarily mean global namespace -- it's just a parameter here and could very well be your own namespace. This doesn't deserve a -1.

Comment: The initial answer only suggested `window[varname] = yourvar;`

Answer (score 1):

**evil solution/hack:** Put the variable you need in a helper object *obj* and avoid having to change current uses to dot notation by using use with(obj){ *your current code*... }

Comment: it should be avoided... it's a bit slower